# Can my app’s name on the Springboard span two lines?

Tags: iphone, springboard

How to show the icon file name,that is app name below the icon on iphone screen  is not showing full name, it is coming with dots.How to show the full name.

Comment: You can have it show the full name by having a shorter name :D

Comment: no  i want to show full name I have Valued Opinions but it is showing Valued....ons like this. I think there is some solution for this

Comment: No, there is no solution to this except for having a shorter name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daniel is right. If your app’s name is too long be displayed whole, the only solution is to make it shorter.

Comment: we can do it.app name does not depend on numbr of characters it depends on width of the application name